# fancybox difficulty

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, fancybox

I have the following mark-up:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="jqueryFancyBox.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <link href="jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.fancybox({
            'showCloseButton': true,
            'hideOnContentClick': true,
            'href': '#popUpAnnouncement',
            'centerOnScroll': true
        });
    });
</script>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div style="display: none" id="popUpAnnouncement">
            <a href="#">close</a>
             lalalalala
        </div>
        <input type="button" id="btn" value="lala" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The modal pops up at pageload but after it closes the div is still shown at the top of the page. How do I hide the div, after it's been closed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it has to do with your problem, probably not. But make sure you place the script tag inside head or body, not between them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onClosed option:

```
      ...
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $.fancybox({
        'showCloseButton': true,
        'hideOnContentClick': true,
        'href': '#popUpAnnouncement',
        'centerOnScroll': true,
        'onClosed': function(){$('#popUpAnnouncement').hide();}
         });
    });
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 ....
```